# Can wine be restricted to running a whitelist of apps?

Tags: wine

I have an app I trust that needs to be run in wine. However, I don't want other users to be able to run just any app in wine because of security concerns. Is there a way to restrict to a list of trusted .exe's?

EDIT:
The application in question does not have an installer. It's a standalone app.

Comment: In case any other can shed some light onto this, there a bunch of people who will be sharing the same account on this machine.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Docs](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Can_I_install_applications_to_be_shared_by_multiple_users.3F):

> **7.2 Can I install applications to be shared by multiple users?**
>
> Wine does not currently allow sharing its configuration ("prefixes") between users, due to the risk of registry corruption from running multiple wineservers simultaneously bug #11112. **At present, applications must be installed separately for each user.**
>
> However, you can copy Wine prefixes; you can install everything to one prefix, then make a copy of it in each user's home directory. This saves running installers repeatedly.

So short answer to what you want is that every user needs to install their own app, so you don't need to worry about that. You can change `wine` permissions so it can only be run by your user.

Comment: This doesn't quite address my problem, other users will be using the same account (it's a shared PC in a lab). Is there a way to restrict what apps can be run by whitelisted paths/executables rather than file permissions?

Comment: The app doesn't have an installer. I edited my question to clarify.

Comment: @Chris Nope, there is no non-convoluted way to do that. You can obscure things, like changing the `wine's` `bin` name, compile your own wine and leave it in `/usr/bin`, or just using OS permission level abilities. Check [this](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#Can_I_install_applications_to_be_shared_by_multiple_users.3F) topic in the official forums

Comment: thanks. The link in your comment sends me to the wiki, not the forums. Did you mean to link to the [bug](https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=11112)? In any case, edit your answer to say it be done and I'll mark it as accepted.